# How to pick localize android app based on the user profile.?

Tags: android, localization

I would like to localize my app based on the user who has logged in my app and not based on the device loacle. How can I achieve this ?

Regards,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: But why? The user specified a locale already. Why ignore it and do your own thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was required for a customer in europe. They want to provide the locale based on user language they chose at the time of registering witht he company.

We ended up implementing it natively through locale change events..